# invalid scope facebook login ionic firebase

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, facebook-authentication

I am developping hybrid app using angularjs ionic and firebase. I try to add login with facebook. This is my code :

```
   var auth = $firebaseAuth( ref); 
   $scope.loginFB = function() {
   $cordovaOauth.facebook("MY FACEBOOK_APP_ID", ["My email"]).then(function(result) {
   auth.$authWithOAuthToken("facebook", result.access_token).then(function(authData) {
   console.log(JSON.stringify(authData));
   Popup('Success', JSON.stringify(authData) ); 
   }, function(error) {
   Popup('error',error); 
   });
   }, function(error) {
   Popup('error',error); 
    });
  }
```

When i run the code in my device. I show this message error : `invalid scope : my email`
How can i fix this problem please.

Answer (score 0):

The scope to request a user's email is `"email"` (where you now have `"My email"`). Also see https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/facebook.html